# Where can I find tests for math parser/engine?

Tags: java, unit-testing, math, testing, junit

Currently i support math parser/engine library (i.e. library that can parse and evaluate expressions). I've already written some jUnit tests but I want 100% test cover. It seems that this tasks must be already solved in the past but i didn't find any tests in the Internet.
The preferred form of tests is text files so I can parse them manually or programmatically but if there are pdf, docs or whatever it also be OK.

It would be great if tests will contain not only arithmetic operations but also symbolic calculations, integration and differentiation tests.

Comment: So what you're looking for is a list of mathematical expressions? Along with their results?

Comment: Exactlty. E.g.: sin(2)=0.909297427 or cos''(t)=-cos(t)

Comment: Have you tried math.stackexchange.com, it's probably more appropriate than here.

Comment: No, I haven't heard about it and I will try, thanks.

Comment: Actually I posted question on math.stackexchange.com and got -1 to question's rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a bunch of tests in the apache commons library [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/math/trunk/src/test/): hope it will cover all cases.